spring cloud loadbalancer No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.ServiceInstanceListSupplier'
When I run a simple GET request to my gateway I obtain this error from gateway:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type
'org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.ServiceInstanceListSupplier'
availa> at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1262)

This is my config class:
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class LoadBalancerConfigurationTest {

    @Profile("test")
    @LoadBalancerClient(name = "captcha", configuration = ServiceAConfiguration.class)
    public class ServiceAConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("captcha")
        public ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceAInstanceListSupplier() {
            return new StaticServiceInstanceListSupplier("-captcha", Arrays.asList(
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("captcha-1", "captcha", "localhost", 9091, false),
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("captcha-2", "captcha", "localhost", 9092, false),
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("captcha-3", "captcha", "localhost", 9093, false)
            ));
        }
    }

    @Profile("test")
    @LoadBalancerClient(name = "service", configuration = ServiceBConfiguration.class)
    public class ServiceBConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("service")
        public ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceBInstanceListSupplier() {
            return new StaticServiceInstanceListSupplier("-service", Arrays.asList(
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("service-1", "service", "localhost", 9094, false),
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("service-2", "service", "localhost", 9095, false),
                    new DefaultServiceInstance("service-3", "service", "localhost", 9096, false)
            ));
        }
    }

    static class StaticServiceInstanceListSupplier implements ServiceInstanceListSupplier {
        private final String serviceId;
        private final List<ServiceInstance> instances;

        StaticServiceInstanceListSupplier(String serviceId, List<ServiceInstance> instances) {
            this.serviceId = serviceId;
            this.instances = instances;
        }

        @Override
        public String getServiceId() {
            return serviceId;
        }

        @Override
        public Flux<List<ServiceInstance>> get() {
            return Flux.just(instances);
        }
    }
}

Does anyboody know where am I wrong?
I need to load balance 2 microservices spring boot webapp where each of them has three instances.
